# How to enable LDAP extension in XAMPP environment

Tags: php, ldap, xampp

I am  trying to enable the LDAP extension in my XAMPP server.

I've tried the following:

- Uncomment the LDAP extension in php.ini
- Added two DLL files: `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` in System32 folder

But LDAP extension is still not in my `phpinfo()` list.

How do I enable LDAP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add correct versions and restart the system it will working...