# Enable LDAP on Xampp Windows

Tags: configuration, xampp, ldap

I want to enable LDAP module on my XAMPP Windows 10, here's the few solutions that I've tried :

1. [Copy dll files to System and System32](http://wptidbits.com/webs/enable-php-ldap-module-in-xampp/) and [uncomment extension=php_ldap.dll in php.ini, both development and production.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932146/how-to-enable-ldap-extension-in-xampp-environment)
2. [Copy libsasl.dll to xampp/apache/bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083853/ldap-configuration-on-xammp)

None of these working, when I opened phpinfo() there is no ldap info showing, which means the ldap hasn't been able to installed. I also added PHP in Windows Path with no success, but either my approach is wrong or that wasn't a solution. Any help appreciated.

Comment: After your first 2 steps, restart apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue and the link you provided [How to enable LDAP extension in XAMPP environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932146/how-to-enable-ldap-extension-in-xampp-environment) ended up being the solution for me.

I copied libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll from C:/Ampps/php to C:/Windows/System32.  I made sure neither of these files were in C:/Windows/System.  From there I enabled extension=php_ldap.dll in the php.ini file.  Ampps has a list you can enable php.ini dll's and if I remember right so does XAMPP.  The last step is to just restart Apache and you should be good to go.

I'm using Windows 10 with Ampps instead of XAMPP but have to think they are pretty close.

Answer (score 6):

1. Make sure the `path\to\xampp\php` directory has the following files

   - libeay32.dll
   - libsasl.dll
   - ssleay32.dll

*Usually, you can find these files in `path\to\xampp\sendmail` - this library also uses them. But if not, try to search for them inside the xampp directory.*

2. Uncomment or add the `ldap` extension in the `php.ini` (`path\to\xampp\php\php.ini`) file

   ```
   extension=ldap
   ```
3. Restart the server
4. Make sure the `path\to\xampp\php` directory is set in the system environment variable `PATH`. To know how to do it, see [this post](https://superuser.com/a/284351/1016360).