# Laravel - How to combine Active Directory Authentication with User Authentication

Tags: laravel, active-directory

I am using Laravel 5.8 for authenticating users from database. Presently, I can login and authenticate the users from the application and database.  However, I want to have a mixed authentication whereby I can also authenticate some users from Active Director. That is,

1. Some users can be registered directly from the application, saved into the database and then login.
2. Some users can be imported from Active Directory and they can also login.

How do I achieve this?

[image: adldap error]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you can use ldap extensions for php/laravel:

```
composer require adldap2/adldap2-laravel
```

Using that you can import ldap users and work with them like `Eloquent` users.
Documentation [here](https://adldap2.github.io/Adldap2-Laravel/).

Comment: Sergey Bogdanov: When I ran composer require adldap2/adldap2-laravel, I got this: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.  See the diagram in my updated code.

Comment: You should install ldap extension: `sudo apt-get install php-ldap`

Comment: Sergey Bogdanov - I'm using Windows OS and XAMPP and it doesn't recognise sudo

Comment: Possibly this can help you with ldap on windows [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47047619/enable-ldap-on-xampp-windows)

Comment: Glad to help you :)